# Regex to remove chords from a text file

Tags: c#, regex, logic

I have a big file (about 20k lines) of music with chords.

I'm trying to make a program to remove the chords from my file.

My regex to find chords is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("([A-G](#|b)*([a-z]|[0-9])*)(/[A-G](#|b)*([a-z]|[0-9])*)*");
```

The problem is a logical problem.

How do I detect if a line of my text have only chords using my regex?

UPDATE:
Sample of the file:

```
C                                     G 
Justo é o Senhor em seus santos caminhos, 
A -             G/B C     D4 D G 
Benigno em todas  as  suas  obras.  (bis) 
G          C          C7 
Perto está  o Senhor, (perto está dos que o invocam,) 
     F   C  D -   G  C               F        G         C F  
De todos que o invocam  (De todos que o invocam) 
C/G G   C                        F C 
Em   verdade. Aleluia! Aleluia!
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the file. Just a couple of lines?

Comment: Why the lowercase letters? They will lines without punctation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^[A-G\d#b\s/-]*$(?:\r\n)?", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This will remove all lines that contain only the letters A through G, `#`, `b`, `/`, `-` or whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can anchor your regex by wrapping it in `^...$`.
This will force it to match entire lines.

You can then loop through `File.ReadLines`, like this:

```
var nonChords = File.ReadLines(path)
                    .Where(s => !regex.IsMatch(s));
```

Comment: I have lines like: C             F  C F   C     G C , if i put the ^ and $, it'll never find a 'chordline'

Comment: @Renanlf: You can modify your regex to match multiple chords: `@"^((...)+\s*)+$"`.